# Does NaN interfere with column concatenation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am attempting to merge two columns which contain strings and nans.
When I attempt to merge them I cannot deal with the nan values.

```
df['col3] = df['col1'] + df['col2']
```

returns only my col2 values

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].map(str) + df['col2'].map(str)
```

returns my nans attached to each other.

If I don't use .map(str) then the .nan values don't concatenate at all.

Is there a way to concatenate two dataframe columns so that if either of them are nan they aren't concatenated. Unless both are nan in which case I do want the return nan.

Example:

```
df
col0    col1    col2    col3
X       A       nan     A
Y       nan     B       B
Z       nan     nan     nan
W       ''      B       B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could index first on the last two columns and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
df['col3'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].ffill(1).col2

   col0 col1 col2 col3
0    X    A  NaN    A
1    Y  NaN    B    B
2    Z  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    W   ''    B    B
```

Comment: How does ffill know that it is filling the missing col2 values with col1? What is the significance of the 1? In reality my dataframe has many more columns than these 2 but I just tried to simplify my example. This SEEMS to work but I don't really understand why. I also have empty strings in Col1 will this work with that?

Comment: `1` is the axis. SO essentially it is setting whatever valid value there is in a row. And if there are only nans, it'll col3 would be a nan too @Violatic

Comment: so if there was an extra column, between these two columns this method would not work? Or at least I'd have to re-order my dataframe for it to work

Comment: So in that case the result should be the concatenation of the valid columns? Could you please update with a more representative example? @Violatic

Comment: Added another column to demonstrate it isn't to interfere. My actual dataframe is 240+ columns and I am combining only two of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is `fillna`

```
df['col3']=df.col2.fillna(df.col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply np.where and in case both values exist I have combine both

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":["A",np.nan,"B",np.nan,"C"],
                       "col2":[np.nan,"B",np.nan,np.nan,"d"]})
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col1'].isnull(),df['col2'],
                      np.where(df['col2'].isnull(),df['col1'],df['col1']+df['col2']))
```

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   A        NaN    A
1   NaN        B    B
2   B        NaN    B
3   NaN      NaN    NaN
4   C          d    Cd
```

Answer (score 0):

`fillna()` and `replace()` is what you're looking for, here's fully working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ["A", "B", "C", np.nan],
    'col2': ["D", "E", np.nan, np.nan]
})

df['col3']= df['col1'].fillna('') + df['col2'].fillna('')
df['col3'] = df['col3'].replace('', np.nan)
print(df)
```

It'll first replace NaN values with empty string and then if both are empty, will replace it back with NaN.

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    D   AD
1    B    E   BE
2    C  NaN    C
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```